# How to convert a normal string to escape characters in Python?

Tags: python

I want to convert string with all escape character.

Input

```
string = "Let's do this"
convert(string)
```

Output

```
Let\'s do this
```

Thank You!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your question is not clear. By escape character do you mean adding new line after certain characters or just want to add backslash do your string?

if you want to add backslash before ' character you can try below.

```
new_string = string.replace("'s", "\\'s")
```

Comment: I guess asker wants for every character which is escape character suffix. It may have multiple character so it's better to use regression expression to replace with global flag.

Comment: Voted up. Regular expression would be much better for replacing. Still he has to clarify his need :).

Comment: "if you want to add backslash before ' character you can try below". Then why look for `'s`? Shouldn't you look for just `'`?